# Smoothness of the sum and product of paired roots (eigenvalues)

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm a little upset to ask the following question which might be naive, but I'm really not familiar with such topics and need help.

Consider a parameter-dependent polynomial equation
\begin{equation}
 a_n(p)\lambda^n + a_{n-1}(p)\lambda^{n-1} + \cdots + a_2(p)\lambda^2
+a_1(p)\lambda + a_0(p) = 0,
\end{equation}
where $p\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is the parameter, and all $a_i(p)$ are
sufficiently smooth in $p$. Suppose that at some critical parameter value, say,
$p^*=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
a_1(0)=a_0(0)=0, ~~a_2(0)\neq0, a_n(0)\neq0
\end{equation}
so the polynomial has a double-zero root.
Let $\lambda_1(p)$ and $\lambda_2(p)$ be the two roots,
continous in $p$, such that $\lambda_1(0)=\lambda_2(0)=0$.

My question is, is it guaranteed that the functions
$\lambda_1(p)+\lambda_2(p)$ and $\lambda_1(p)\lambda_2(p)$ are smooth
in $p$, at least in a neighborhood of $p=0$?

Intuitively I thought this might be true, but I don't know how to confirm
it or give any counterexamples to deny it. Can someone enlight me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear in the text, but I mean $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are those two roots which take zero value at $p=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder under polynomial division of a polynomial $a(λ)$ by a quadratic term $b(λ)=λ^2+b_1λ+b_0$ is a smooth function as it is  polynomial in the coefficients. The derivative of this 2D valued function $r(λ)=a(λ)\mod b(λ)$ for the coefficients $b_0,b_1$ is regular if the two factors $b(λ)$ and $c(λ)$ in $a(λ)=b(λ)c(λ)+r(λ)$ are relative prime.

In the given situation the factorization at $p=0$ with the quadratic factor $λ^2$ is relative prime as $a_2(0)\ne 0$. Thus one can by the implicit function theorem the quadratic factor locally to $b(p,λ)=λ^2+b_1(p)λ+b_0(p)$ so that it really is a factor of $a(p,λ)$. The continuation is analytical as solution of an algebraic system.

By Viete, the product of the roots is $b_0(p)$ and the sum of the roots $-b_1(p)$.

[See *Bairstow method* for a loosely related numerical method.]

Comment: Thank you very much! The use of the implicit function theorem seems so brilliant. I think this is just what I want.  However, I can't see through why it is correct that "the map from $(b_0, b_1)$ to $(r_0, r_1)$ is regular if $b(\lambda)$ and $c(\lambda)$ are relative prime", (if the remainder is $r_1\lambda+r_0$).

Comment: I think this can be avoided by directly considering the specific case as I described. But I still want to know whether it is a theorem or some kind of famous fact.

Comment: This is used in numerical factorizations for instance in Schönhage's circle splitting method where approximate initial factors are computed via FFT realizing the generalized Cauchy integral formula and then refined via a Newton method. The computation of the Newton step is only stable if the root sets of the factors are well separated.

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer and comment. Thanks!